# Suggestion list stuck in loading in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes when I want to code I see that the suggestion list is not visible.

I tried `option` + `esc` and `command` + `I` but it says it is in loading. I even waited but it is still in loading.

[image]

I even tried restarting my vscode but it didn't fix.

Can you help me to enable this list because I need this list.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Mine started doing it this morning and it's driving me nuts. Reloading with extensions disabled doesn't change anything. Have tried reinstalling and didn't help either.

Comment: I've since switched to the Insiders version and it seems to have fixed it.
https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/